# Pandas: how to concisely detrend subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate and subtract the average over a subset of columns. Here is one way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def col_avg(df, col_ids):
    '''Calculate and subtract average over *col_ids*

    *df* is modified in-place.
    '''

    cols = [ df.columns[i] for i in col_ids ]
    acc = df[cols[0]].copy()
    for col in cols[1:]:
        acc += df[col]
    acc /= len(cols)
    for col in cols:
        df[col] -= acc

# Create example data
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random((433,80)) + np.arange(433)[:, np.newaxis],
                  columns=['col-%d' % x for x in range(80)])
#df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data.csv')

# Calculate average over columns 2, 3 and 6
df_old = df.copy()
col_avg(df, [ 1, 2, 5])
assert any(df_old.iloc[0] != df.iloc[0])
```

Now and I don't particularly like the two for loops, so I tried to express the same operation more concisely:

```
def col_avg(df, col_ids):
    dfT = df.T
    mean = dfT.iloc[col_ids].mean()
    dfT.iloc[col_ids] -= mean
```

This implementation looks a lot nicer (IMO), but it has one drawback: it only works for some datasets. With the example above, it works. But e.g. when loading [this csv file](https://trialphaenergy.box.com/shared/static/qwmfgaocv1xfmfa4aikdfud0t2b7st0z.csv) it fails.

The only explanation that I have is that in some cases the `dfT.iloc[col_ids]` expression must be internally creating a copy of the value array instead of modifying it in-place.

- Is this the right explanation?
- If so, what is it about the DataFrame that makes pandas decide to copy the data in one case but no the other?
- Is there another way to perform this task that always works and does not require explicit iteration?

**EDIT**: When suggesting alternative implementations, please state why you think your implementation will *always* work. After all, the above code seems to work for some inputs as well.

Comment: How does it fail? Can you edit the question to provide more details?

Comment: Why can't you slice the columns array, i.e. `df.columns[col_ids]`, since your columns are zero-indexed and thus column `i` corresponds with `'col-i'`?  Then you can just do `df[df.columns[col_ids]].mean()`.

Comment: Looking at the CSV file you attached, is your real question how to compute the average over (and subtract it from) all similar columns, e.g. all columns that start with `'Psi'` or  `'coil-'`?

Comment: @Jezzamon: the `df` object is unmodified after the function returns and the assertion fails.

Comment: @wflynny Yes, in my actual code I'm averaging over "similar" columns. Yes, I could do `df[list_of_column_names]`, but do I have any guarantee that I can do in-place editing on the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transpose of the DataFrame, `dfT = df.T`, may return a new DataFrame, not a view.
In that case, modifying `dfT` does nothing to `df`.

In your toy example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random((433,80)) + np.arange(433)[:, np.newaxis],
                  columns=['col-%d' % x for x in range(80)])
```

all the columns have the same dtype:

```
In [83]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 433 entries, 0 to 432
Data columns (total 80 columns):
col-0     433 non-null float64
col-1     433 non-null float64
col-2     433 non-null float64
...          
dtypes: float64(80)
memory usage: 274.0 KB
```

whereas in the DataFrame built from CSV, some columns have `int64` dtype:

```
In [55]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 492 entries, 0 to 491
Data columns (total 72 columns):
sample no                       492 non-null int64
index                           492 non-null int64
plasma-r                        492 non-null float64
plasma-z                        492 non-null float64
...
```

Columns of a DataFrame always have a single dtype. So when you transpose this
CSV-based `df`, the new DataFrame can not be formed by simply transposing a
single underlying NumPy array. The integers which were in columns by themselves
is now spread across rows. Each *column* of `df.T` must have a single dtype, so
the integers are upcasted to floats. So all the columns of `df.T` have dtype
`float64`.  Data has to be copied when dtypes change.

The bottom line is: So when `df` has mixed types, `df.T` is a copy.

---

`col_avg` could be simplified to

```
def col_avg2(df, col_ids):
    means = df.iloc[:, col_ids].mean(axis=1)
    for i in col_ids:
        df.iloc[:, i] -= means
```

Note that the *expression* `df.iloc[:, col_ids]` will return a copy since `cols_ids` is not a basic slice. But *assignment* to `df.iloc[...]` (or `df.loc[...]`) is guaranteed to modify `df`.

This is why assigning to `df.iloc` or `df.loc` is the recommended way to avoid the [assignment-with-chained-indexing pitfall](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail).

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense! But about your proposed `col_avg2`: why can't we just use `df.iloc[:, col_ids] =- means`? I tried it and just makes everything NaN while warning about *unorderable types: str() < int(), sort order is undefined for incomparable objects*. What is going wrong here?

Comment: `df.iloc[:, col_ids] -= means` does not work because the broadcasting happens in the wrong direction. Look at `df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), index=list('ABCD'))` and `df - df[0]` to get an idea of what goes wrong. The standard workaround for this is `df.subtract(df[0], axis=0)`. Analogously, you could replace the `for-loop` in `col_avg2` with `df.iloc[:, col_ids] = df.iloc[:, col_ids].subtract(means, axis=0)`. This creates a new temporary DataFrame on the right-hand side, so it requires more memory but can be faster than the `for-loop`, especially if `len(col_ids)` is large.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question, this does what you are asking.  I don't understand why you're transposing the dataframe.  Note: I got rid of the string column names for simplicity, but you can replace those easily.

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random((6,8)) + np.arange(6)[:, np.newaxis])#,
                  #columns=['col-%d' % x for x in range(80)])

# Calculate average over columns 2, 3 and 6
df_old = df.copy()
col_ids=[1,2,5]
df[col_ids] = df[col_ids] - np.mean(df[col_ids].values)
df_old-df # to make sure average is calculated over all three columns

Out[139]:
    0   1           2           3   4   5           6   7
0   0   2.950637    2.950637    0   0   2.950637    0   0
1   0   2.950637    2.950637    0   0   2.950637    0   0
2   0   2.950637    2.950637    0   0   2.950637    0   0
3   0   2.950637    2.950637    0   0   2.950637    0   0
4   0   2.950637    2.950637    0   0   2.950637    0   0
5   0   2.950637    2.950637    0   0   2.950637    0   0
```

Comment: I don't think this technically solves OPs problem, as I think the string based names are key and in reality don't map `i -> 'col-i'`.  See the csv file in the OP.  However, this is the correct direction.

Comment: This might be what OP needs to get the rest of the way?: `col_ids = [col for col in df.columns.values if col.startswith('Psi')]`

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: I'm transposing because there is no `.iloc` for columns, only for rows.

Comment: I think you're missing the elephant in the room :-). My code works, your code works. But since that seems to depend on the input data, I don't trust that it will work for every input. The main question is, how can I ensure that whatever slicing/indexing I use will not create a copy?

Answer (score 0):

OP, say you want the average computed over similar columns and subtracted (say the "Psi at ..." columns).  The easiest way is

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

psi_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('Psi')]
df[psi_cols] -= df[psi_cols].mean().mean()
```

This computes the total mean across all columns.  If you want to subtract the column mean from each column, do

```
df[psi_cols] -= df[psi_cols].mean()
```

Comment: Is `df[psi_cols] -= <sth>` guaranteed to modify `df`? It seems to work, but so does my example. (And the subtraction has to be by row, so you've got one `mean()` too many. But that's not that's not the real issue).

Comment: `df[cols] -= <sth>` is equivalent to `df[cols] = df[cols] - <sth>`.

Comment: No, it's not. That's a common pitfall actually. But even if it were, why is it guaranteed that `df[coils]` will in-place modify the existing columns? It could be copying some data around.

Comment: Yeah I think in this case it is, as `df[cols]` is a view of `df`.  That statement isn't true in which there is chained indexing, i.e. multiple called to `__getitem__` and would raise an assignment to copy warning.  If you want to be a pedant, you can substitute `df.loc[:, cols]` in for `df[cols]`.